# Code request for a loop searching for primes with certain condition

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, prime-numbers

I am stuck in trying to understand how to write a code (perhaps a for-cycle, or a do-while?) that returns the values of $n$ for which $$2^n + 1$$ is a prime, but searching only amongst the values of $n$ that are a multiple of $4$.

For example: for $n = 4, 8, 16$ we have $2^n + 1$ is prime.

So I need a code that search among the $n = 2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, in a given range, like all the

I though about something like

```
Module[{list = {}, k}, 
For[k = 0, k < 100, k++, If[PrimeQ[2^k + 1], AppendTo[list, k]]];
list]
```

but this does seach among all the natural $k$ in that given range, not among the multiple of $4$ only...

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing `k++` to `k+=4` Do a little experiment with a For loop and print k to confirm that it works as you want

Comment: @Bill Wow, that was a rather cool trick!

Comment: For example: `Table[If[PrimeQ[2^(2 k) + 1], {2 k, 2^(2 k) + 1}, Nothing], {k, 1, 
  10}]`

Comment: `Select[Range[0, 100, 4], PrimeQ[2^# + 1] &]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most imperative and idiomatic way has already been proposed in comments by Bob Hanlon:

```
n= 15000;

Select[Range[0, n, 4], PrimeQ[2^# + 1] &]
(* {0, 4, 8, 16} *)
```

It is *very* clean and readable, and it takes a reasonable 44.2 seconds on my machine (all times obtained with `AbsoluteTiming`).

---

The equivalent `For` approach, modified from your code, takes 51.6 seconds:

```
Module[{k, list = {}},
  For[
    k = 0, k <= n, k = k + 4,
    If[PrimeQ[2^k + 1], AppendTo[list, k]]
  ]
]
```

A significant improvement is obtained by replacing `AppendTo` with the typically better-performing `Sow` and `Reap` combination (46.0 seconds):

```
Module[{k},
  Reap[
    For[
      k = 0, k <= n, k = k + 4,
      If[PrimeQ[2^k + 1], Sow[k]]
    ]
  ][[2, 1]]
]
```

Using `Do` leads to similar timing.

---

Since your problem is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) (i.e. each task is completely independent of the others), it should be a good candidate for effective parallelization.

The first example below uses [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) to handle all the complication of distributing work to the kernels and re-assembling the chunks into one result. This takes 23.8 seconds on my 4-core laptop, a significant speedup:

```
ParallelTable[
  If[PrimeQ[2^i + 1], i, Nothing],
  {i, 0, n, 4}
]
```

Similar performance can be obtained with [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) and straightforward parallelization of the primality test (24.7 seconds):

```
With[{r = Range[0, n, 4]},
  Pick[
    r,
    ParallelMap[PrimeQ, 2^r + 1]
  ]
]
```

Comment: This is simply WONDERFUL.

Comment: @Numb3rs I am delighted that it helped!